# Slick Carousel Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to get a simple implementation of the Slick Carousel working.

I've followed the instructions at the Git page: https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick

Here is my code.  Can anyone see a problem?  Does anyone have a simple working code sample for slick?

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>My Now Amazing Webpage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.7/slick.css"/>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: lightblue">

    <div class="your-class">
        <div><p>test1</p></div>
        <div><p>test2</p></div>
        <div><p>test3</p></div>
    </div>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.7/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.your-class').slick();
        });
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

The reason it's not working is because you are running your html from file. This means that the url scheme being used for your script links is

```
file:
```

instead of

```
http:
```

so your CDN links are being resolved as

```
file://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js
```

which is clearly incorrect.

Either hard-wire the scheme to `http:` by updating all the links to contain a scheme:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
  href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.7/slick.css"/>
```

or run your code from an http context instead of from a file on your HD.

Comment: Thank You!  Works after changing to http: