# how to solve Slick carousel jquery conflict issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I tried the [Slick carousel](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) only with foundation and it works. But when I integrate with my MVC framework, just doesn't work. Basically there are more than one javascript plugin I'm using on the front end. SO I believe it's due to jquery conflict.

My script which I placed before `</body>` tag

```
</script>
    <!--<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>-->(I have to comment this otherwise the another banner plugin doesnt work)
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/8.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $data['config']['THEME_DIR']; ?>/js/slick.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $data['config']['THEME_DIR']; ?>/js/script.js"></script>
```

CSS placed in the header but it doesn't seem to give any effect bbut thats not a problem now.

```
<link href="<?php echo $data['config']['THEME_DIR']; ?>/css/foundation/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

HTML

```
<section id="features" class="blue">
            <div class="content">


                <h2>Autoplay</h2>
                <div class="slider autoplay">
                    <div><h3>1</h3></div>
                    <div><h3>2</h3></div>
                    <div><h3>3</h3></div>
                    <div><h3>4</h3></div>
                    <div><h3>5</h3></div>
                    <div><h3>6</h3></div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </section
```

I refered to [Slick Carousel Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25985501/slick-carousel-not-working)..
But I dont get it.

Help is badly needed.Thanks all.

EDITED
I added http:

```
<script src="**http:**//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="**http:**//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="**http:**//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/8.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $data['config']['THEME_DIR']; ?>/js/slick.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $data['config']['THEME_DIR']; ?>/js/script.js"></script>
```

Now the Slick works but banner plugin doesnt. It's because I uncomented

```
<script src="**http:**//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

Can anyone tell me how do I solve this conflict?

Comment: `var js = jQuery.noConflict();` to jquery conflict issue

Comment: @Glizzweb, but can you also tell me where to place it in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var jq = jQuery.noConflict();` is what you need.
You'll need to replace either $ or jQuery in the Afflicted plugins. Make sure not to use the same variable name in either.